# Highlight link not showing in Webstorm 11

Tags: dart, webstorm

Pressing CTRL and pointing the mouse to a package does not show the underline link in WebStorm 11.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Is Dart language support enabled? (File > Settings... > Languages & Frameworks > Dart > Enable Dart support for the project '...')

Comment: Yest - all projects are enabled.

Comment: Auto-completion works? Do you have more than one Dart project in one WebStorm project? Do you use `--no-package-symlinks` for `pub get`/`pub upgrade`? I didn't have any issues with that for quite some time.

Comment: Auto-completion does not work. Yes, I do have more that one Dart project in a WebStorm project. However, each subproject is a valid Dart project itself - it is added as a subproject to WebStorm. No to --no-package-symlinks. I use Stagehand to generate project and it still adds the packages directory as well as the .packages file. Can I discard the packages directory now?

Comment: No, keep the directory for now. Can you please try to open a single Dart project in WebStorm and check navigation and auto-completion again?

Comment: My .html custom-components are highlighted as links and I am taken to the original files when the link is clicked. However, none of the libraries or Dart classes shows any similar links with ctrl+spacebar. in a single Dart project.

Comment: Thanks anyway Gunter.